# Problems with Imagelist after migration

Tags: delphi, components, vcl

i recently got my hands on Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and started to migrate a project made with Delphi XE4. While my application works as before, i have a strange problem with the images saved in a TImageList. This image list is connected to a TCategoryButtons group. The image list holds 16x16px transparent PNG files. The goal of showing the images transparent in the panel works during design time, but not during runtime any more. During runtime, black appears where the image was transparent before.

[image]

- The TImageList has these settings:

  BkColor=clNone, BlendColor=clNone, ColorDepth=32bit, DrawingStyle=dsTransparent
- The application uses themes

What i tried:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the whole project
- making changes to the image list contents (added/removed images)
- tried different settings in the image list
- Made a new project, added TCategoryPanel and TImageList, loaded the same images and settings, added a theme -> This works O.O

Did someone had these effects before and knows how to resolve them? Why does this work while in design time, but not in runtime?

Comment: Transparent PNGs are actually not as you expect. It doesn't use the transparency as found in PNGs. Instead, use a solid color and set that color as the transparent color on the image list.

Comment: @JerryDodge I would accept his if it would behave the same way during design and runtime - if this is the error case. But because it worked before and works if i create a new project, this has to be something project-related.

Comment: The latest update of Tokyo has a TPngImageList that seems to work correctly.

Comment: I have Version 25.0.29039.2004 is this the latest update? Is there an update feature i miss?

Comment: Does your version have a TPngImageList? You can use that instead of the TImageList.

Comment: @RonMaupin Oh, no, it doesnt have it.

Comment: It is in Tokyo 10.2.2.

Comment: I have `Embarcadero® Delphi 10.2 Version 25.0.29039.2004`, which seems to be what you have. Use the GetIt Package Manager to get the TPngImageList.

Comment: Haven't you used e.g. CnWizards?

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for the tip. I would prefer "fixing" my existing version instead of reloading all of the images (there are a lot...). That the same list works with a new project baffles me the most - any ideas on this? Is there a "rebuild image resources" approach?

Comment: @Victoria I did not know CnWizards before. I try to use as few third-party components as possible because of the hassle to set everything up again on a new version

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Design-Time and Run-Time are not *supposed* to look the same. There are plenty other differences between the two, such as buttons.

Comment: @JerryDodge yeah ok, thats an argument. BUT if i copy the same panel and image list into a new project, it works as intended! I assume something like dfm file corruption? Maybe my question is more like "how do i repair my project" instead of "how i accomplish png images in an image list"...

Comment: Well, just the fact that the latest version of Delphi introduces `TPngImageList` when the existing `TImageList` already supported transparency on multiple file types, tells me there's something very deep going on, which was easier for them to solve by creating a brand new component, instead of patching the existing one. Just a hunch.

Comment: I don't think your first comment is right @jerry. 32 bit pngs use an alpha channel with partial transparency.

Comment: @David I don't mean PNGs themselves, I meant how Delphi handles PNGs.

Comment: @Jerry Well, delphi VCL image lists are just wrappers of the windows control which has full support for partial transparency.

Comment: @JP My advice is to stop storing images in dfm files. Link the png files as resources and load them at runtime. Then you'll be free from the problems. And you'll have proper version control of your assets.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i always like your suggestion here on SO. Will keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: @all i now solved my problems by analyzing the differences between a freshly created project file and my existing. I recreated the .dproj file by deleting it and then reapplied my old changes manually per Project - Options. It now works, yay!

Comment: @JerryDodge, TPngImageList actually exists for a very long time. It is just in recent versions that it is available via GetIt. So it is not Embarcadero that introduced TPngImageList to the latest Delphi versions. It just made it easier to obtain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problems by analyzing the differences between a freshly created project file and my existing. I recreated the .dproj file by deleting it and then reapplied my old changes manually per Project - Options. This fixed my problems with the images.

Comment: Let me guess: it were the runtime themes?

Comment: I tested with and without runtime themes, there were no difference. I then just wrote down my important settings and deleted the .proj file. Maybe this was the culprit: ProjectVersion jumped from 14.6 to 18.3

Comment: Judging by your screenshots, yes, that's most likely what the issue was. Note how the scrollbar is still the extremely old style.

Comment: @JerryDodge I actually use the "Classic Windows Style" on this PC

Comment: No, you're mistaken. VCL Styles are an entirely different topic. Runtime Themes are a different story.

Comment: Oh, just read up on Runtime themes. I dont know if they were set in the old project, but now they are.